# Connect Oracle SQL Developer to HP Service Manager

Tags: sql, oracle, connection, hp-service-manager

I want to extract data from HP Service Manager by using Oracle SQL Developer. How exactly do I make the connection to Service Manager from SQL Developer? I am new to both of these tools.

I have seen many examples of connecting to an oracle localhost database, but haven't find yet any example or tutorial for connecting to HP Service Manager.

Comment: what database platform does HP Service Manager use?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use a database tool to connect to an HP product?

Comment: I was given Oracle connection strings by a colleague, but I'm just not experienced with Oracle tools.

Comment: if you can't parse the connection string they shared to a sql developer connection properties dialog, I would ask your college for help. or, give us a anonymous version of your string here, and i'll translate it for you